# How to convert sqldatareader to list of dto's?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ado.net, repository, dto

I just started moving all my ado.net code from the asp.net pages to repo's and created dto's for each table (manually), but now I don't know what is a good efficient way to convert a sqldatareader to a list of my dto objects?

For example sake, my dto is Customer.

I am using webforms and I am NOT using an ORM. I would like to start slow and work my way up there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a short example on how you can retrieve your data using a data reader:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Your_Server_Name;Initial Catalog=Your_Database_Name;Integrated Security=SSPI;")) {
    cnn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn)) {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            // Get ordinals (column indexes) from the customers table
            int custIdOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("CustomerID");
            int nameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Name");
            int imageOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Image");
            while (reader.Read()) {
                var customer = new Customer();
                customer.CustomerID = reader.GetInt32(custIdOrdinal);
                customer.Name = reader.IsDBNull(nameOrdinal) ? null : reader.GetString(nameOrdinal);
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(imageOrdinal)) {
                    var bytes = reader.GetSqlBytes(imageOrdinal);
                    customer.Image = bytes.Buffer;
                }
                customers.Add(customer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If a table column is nullable then check `reader.IsDBNull` before retrieving the data.

Comment: Is it better to convert the datatypes from the datareader in the obect?

Comment: It is usually better to place the data-access logic (DAL) at a different place. If the data migrates to a different database in future, it will be much easier to convert the DAL. Otherwise, the code will be spread all over your application. If you still want to do it in the Customer class, then you will have to create static methods that return customer lists. You could also pass a customer id or a data reader to the constructor and do the conversions there or at least call the separate DAL from there.

Answer (score 7):

Usually the pattern looks something like:

```
List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();

using(SqlDataReader rdr = GetReaderFromSomewhere()) {
  while(rdr.Read()) {
     Customer cust = new Customer();
     cust.Id = (int)rdr["Id"];
     list.Add(cust)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defenitly should look at [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) - this simple wrapper over ADO.NET

```
var table = new Customer();
//grab all
var customers = table.All();
//just grab from customer 4. This uses named parameters
var customerFour = table.All(columns: "CustomerName as Name", where: "WHERE customerID=@0",args: 4);
```