# How to put the first value of a list item to a text box in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the data from a table and am storing it in the following way.

```
while (results.Read())
{
    ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
    newItem.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
    newItem.Value = results["ID"].ToString();
}
```

Now there is a text box to which i need to put my first value of the list. How to achieve this?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I tried my level best and am new to .Net. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Since you are new, I will offer this advice.  I'm guessing the "results" is an IDataReader (or similar).  You are mixing Data Access code with UI concerns.  I would create a basic DTO object, and push everything into a collection of the DTO objects....and then you will have a collection in memory.......and then you can use LINQ and a "FirstOrDefault" method.  Here is a start up post about basic DTO stuff : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249223/how-to-convert-sqldatareader-to-list-of-dtos

Comment: Thanks grandaCode. That what exactly i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
Boolean assignedFirst = false;

while (results.Read()) {
  if (!assignedFirst) {
    textBox1.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
    assignedFirst = true;
  }
  ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
  newItem.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
  newItem.Value = results["ID"].ToString();
}
```

---

An alternate way.  Your comment stated you have 5 of these to do:

```
Int32 i = 0;
while (results.Read()) {
  switch(i) {
    case 0: 
      textBox1.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
      break;
    case 1:
      textBox2.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
      break;
    case 2:
      textBox3.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
      break;
    case 3:
      textBox4.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
      break;
    case 4:
      textBox5.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
      break;
  }
  i++;

      ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
      newItem.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
      newItem.Value = results["ID"].ToString();

}
```

Comment: So is it like if I have 5 text box i will put the same logic and add 5 more boolean varaiables?

Comment: Yes.  Although you might consider a different screen design.  Maybe use a repeater for the 5 or so text boxes and simply databind the results to the repeater.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (results.Read())
{
    if (String.isNullOrEmpty(txt.Text))
    {
        txt.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
    }
    ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
    newItem.Text = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
    newItem.Value = results["ID"].ToString();
}
```